# looping through text document with set column numbers (3) but variable length

Tags: c#

Hi I'm wondering what the best way to loop this txt doc
and extract the rows as separated values in separate arrays

```
 ItemType1  ItemType2  ItemType3\n
 1.0000009  KKKiiiNNG  ItemTypeC\n
 1.7777777  SNJLJXSSS  ItemTypeC\n
 2.0000000  MMNNXXGGG  ItemTypeC\n
 ...can have more or less line
```

Hope it makes sense...
Thanks

Comment: What's your expect result?

Comment: Are they tabs or spaces between columns?

Comment: ItemType1 - is start times, ItemType2 - stop times, ItemType3 - word.
Spaces between all words (only ever 3 col wide)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `File.ReadLines` to read each line words and use the [string.Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Split_System_Char___) function to split the words of line by whitespace. The documentation shows that passing `null` splits on whitespace characters:

> If the separator parameter is null or contains no characters, white-space characters are assumed to be the delimiters. White-space characters are defined by the Unicode standard and return true if they are passed to the [Char.IsWhiteSpace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.iswhitespace?view=netframework-4.7.2) method.

Due to `ReadLines` will return words by each line to a string array.

```
[0] = 1.0000009  KKKiiiNNG  ItemTypeC
[1] = 7777777  SNJLJXSSS  ItemTypeC
....
```

next step we can use lambda `select` to get result instead for loop

> Selects collection and transforms elements in a collection. Can be overloaded to get element index, selects and rounds down each number in the array.

```
var result = File.ReadLines("your file path")
                             .Select(x=>x.Split(null))
                             .Select(z=> new {
                                 ItemType1 = z[0],
                                 ItemType2 = z[1],
                                 ItemType3 = z[2]
                             });
```

Here is a link about [linq and labdma tutorial](https://linqsamples.com/linq-to-objects/projection/Select)

Comment: I can read the txt file and see the data - 
but am stuck on the looping (super newbie ><)

Comment: @StackBuddy My example is using linq to instead of loop. did you want to use loop version?

Comment: @D-ShihI think your answer is good, maybe just explain how Linq works (how its similar to looping).  OP is new so they will need some detailed explanation

Comment: @maccettura Ok wait a second I will write more explain

Comment: lambda expression is interesting...! am currently youtubing it
it will take a while to wrap my head around it though Ill keep looking at it.

Comment: so cool Ill have a look again in the morning, thanks so much for the help and also the cool new technique! hadn't seen that done before! - it
most likely it will be the sexiest piece of code on my page :P

Comment: I add more explain hope can help you:)